# Problem while bootstraping ubuntu chef node from chefDK on windows workstation

Tags: ssh, chef-infra, knife, chefdk

I'm new to Chef and I have stuck in a problem. I'm using **AWS Chef Automate Server** and **EC2 ubuntu** instance as Chef Node. My workstation is local machine where I have installed **ChefDK on windows**. I have successfully configured the Chef server with ChefDK.

When I bootstrap the node using **Knife Bootstrap** command, it bootstraps the ubuntu node but shows this error in the end `cannot create /etc/chef/trusted_certs/opsworks-cm-ca-2016-root.pem: Directory nonexistent`

The command I used here is `knife bootstrap myEC2PublicIPHere -N UmaidNode1 -x ubuntu --sudo --run-list "recipe[nginx]" -i .chef/my_key.pem`.

After that I added some other cookbooks in the server and run **Knife ssh** command from my windows workstation to run **Chef-client** on the node, but this command is not working. I have tried it with different attributes, but always the similar issue `FATAL: 1 node found, but does not have the required attribute to establish the connection. Try setting another attribute to open the connection using --attribute`.

The command I tried here is `knife ssh 'name:*' --attribute myEC2PublicIpHere -x ubuntu -i .chef/my_key.pem 'sudo chef-client'`.
Furthur upon running this command `knife node show UmaidNode1`, it shows the data about node where IP is blank. I don't know why it is not getting this IP here. Showing the output `Node Name:   UmaidNode1 Environment: _default FQDN: IP: Run List:    recipe[nginx], recipe[apache] Roles: Recipes: Platform: Tags:`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhOsE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is finally resolved. I don't know why, but the problem was with the **ChefDK version**. I was using the latest **version 4.8.23**. It always creates directory `/etcchef` but the chef searches for all files in the directory `/etc/chef`. So it was unable to get the files like client.rb etc.

**NOTE:** I even make the required  `/etc/chef` directory by myself, but it didn't work.
I installed an older version of ChefDK and now it's working fine.